# Query Results inside the javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask if is it possible to pass a query result inside the javascript? I am using asp.net mvc here. Everytime the user clicks on the details,  I would like that it will prompt the name or email using the ID passed in that action.

```
public ActionResult Details(int rf_id = 0)
    {
        var check = db.rms_approval_route_vw.Where(s => s.rf_id == rf_id).FirstOrDefault();
        var sample = "hey";
        var str = "";
        if (check != null)
        {
            sample = check.c_email;
            str = check.c_email + check.centMan;
            return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>alert(str);</script>");
            //return PartialView(check);
        }

        return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>var str = 'hey';alert(str);</script>");

    }
```

I got an error here saying that `str` is not defined.
Why?
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>alert(str);</script>");
```

`str` is not a JavaScript variable. You need to add that string to the retunred `Content` properly:

```
return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + str + "');</script>");
```

Comment: In that case, please consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), @IamGlads.

Comment: How I wish to consider it as an answer but this time, I don't have enough points to vote.

Comment: You don't need "points" to accept an answer. You can just click the check mark under the answer's vote count.